# Printing floating point numbers 4.5e-45f, 4.8e-45f and 5.1e-45f returns strange results

Tags: c++, floating-point

The following C++ program prints three different 32 bit floats, with strange results. Can anyone explain?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "result1 = "<<4.5e-45f <<std::endl;
  std::cout << "result2 = "<<4.8e-45f<<std::endl;
  std::cout << "result3 = "<<5.1e-45f<<std::endl;

}
```

The results are

```
result1 = 4.2039e-45
result2 = 4.2039e-45
result3 = 5.60519e-45
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 32 bit float can only store numbers down to about 1.18E-38.  Smaller values than that can be stored, but they will be *denormalized*, which is stored with lower precision.  The numbers you are trying to display are right at the limit of what can be distinguished from zero, so there will be a large error in the actual stored value compared with the number you are trying to store.  If you need to use numbers that small use a `double`.

Comment: @zell Floats are normally stored with the most significant bit 1, akin to "1.37E-5" in a decimal number.  In a denormalized number, this MSB is 0 with the numeric value stored as the fraction, as if you'd write "0.03E-5".  Look up IEEE floating point numbers for further details.